# How to Display the Month, Day of the Month, and Current Time Plus Twelve Hours?

Tags: php, date, time, weekday

I am looking for help with my PHP code:

```
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
echo "The current server timezone is: " . $date;
$jd=cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"));
echo(jddayofweek($jd,1));
```

Currently this outputs:

```
The current server timezone is: 03/28/2014 01:27:17 pm Friday
```

I am trying to make this display the current month, day of the month, and the current time plus twelve hours. For example, the output would be:

```
 The current server timezone is: March 28 Friday at 1:27 am Friday
```

If anyone can help it will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Use DateTime objects: `echo (new DateTime('+12 hours'))->format('F j l \a\t g:i a l');` (For a list of available formatting options, have a look at the [documentation for `date()`](http://php.net/date))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OOP style:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('now');
$dateTime->add(new DateInterval('PT12H'));
echo $dateTime->format('F j l \a\\t h:i a l');
```

Or just with DateTime:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('+12 hours');
echo $dateTime->format('F j l \a\\t h:i a l');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JJUtIC)

Comment: You could even make this a one-liner if you wanted to

Comment: This doesn't display the day of the week, may I offer an exchange of up votes anyways?

Comment: Edit it to display day of week.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use [Ouzo Goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies) in your project then Clock looks neat.

```
Clock::now()->plusHours(12)->format('F j l \a\\t h:i a l');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('F j l \a\\t h:i a l', strtotime('+12 hours'));
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sL7bM3)

It has the day of the week twice as requested. Not sure if you really want that, though.